# Looking for clear,concise refactor of web hooks example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Ok so I am trying to understand React Hooks and how to update
my code to grab the JSON from the source below and show the data. I'm clear on importing the hook and initializing it with useState(0) but my code fails when I try to re-factor within my fetch statement. Any/all help would be greatly appreciated...see below.

```
// import React, { Component } from 'react';
import React, { useState  } from 'react';
import Feeder from './Feeder';
import Error from './Error';

// class NewsFeeder extends Component {
//  constructor(props) {
//    super(props);
//    this.state = {
//      news: [],
//      error: false,
//    };
//  }
const [hideNews,showNews] = useState(0);

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://newsfeed.com`;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          news: data.articles
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: true
        })
      });
  }

  renderItems() {
    if (!this.state.error) {
      return this.state.news.map((item) => (
        <FeedPrime key={item.url} item={item} />
      ));
    } else {
      return <Error />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.renderItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewsFeeder;
```

Comment: With a small component like this, I would suggest you start from scratch following some tutorials for function based components, then implement fetch in there. What you have at the moment isn't a valid component.

Answer (score 1):

React hooks are created for functional components and are not ment to be used in class components.
Here is a table of the functionality and the way to achive it using classes and functions with hooks.

| component type | state | `fetch` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| class | store the state in `this.state` that you only assign once in the constructor, use `this.setState` to modify the state | do your `fetch` logic in `componentDidMount` |
| function | create a pair of `[example, setExample]` with `useState` | do `fetch` in `useEffect` hook |

Using `fetch` with hooks: (edited version of [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/)):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

    useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await fetch('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux').then(response => response.json());

        setData(result);
    });

    let items = data.hits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
            <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
    ));

    return (
       <ul>
           {items}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default App;
```